# Gauss-Markov theorem - What do you mean by linearity in parameters?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, linear-model

What does it exactly mean by `linearity in parameters` in the assumptions for classical linear regression model and Gauss-Markov theorem?

My understanding is:

1. `y = b0 + b1 x + e` - Linear in parameters
2. `y = b3 + b4^2 x + e` - Non-linear in parameters => Can it be re-written like `y = b3 + b5 x + e` where `b5 = b4^2`

In case 2, since final values of all `b's` are nothing but constants ultimately, we can rewrite `b4^2` as some other constant `b5`. So if we rewrite this, case 2 also becomes linear in parameters. Isn't it?

e.g

1. `y = 10 + 16 x + e` (Linear in parameter)
2. `y = 10 + 5^2 x + e` (Non-linear in parameter) but can be re-written as `y = 10 + 25 x + e` which is linear in parameter.

Please help me to clarify what I'm lacking to undestand.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Similar questions were asked on other stackexchange sites, see [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12274/what-does-linear-in-parameters-mean) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426836/linear-regression-model-linearity-in-parameters-variables).

Answer (score 3):

First thing is that we're essentially dealing with a vector of parameters, so that we can consider that we have $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\beta_0,\beta_1,...,\beta_p)^\top$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra and/or  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map and notice (working in the notation of the second link, and writing $\sum_{j=0}^p \beta_j x_j$ as $X\boldsymbol{\beta}$), that $f(\boldsymbol{\beta})=E(Y|x)=X\boldsymbol{\beta}$ satisfies the two conditions in the definition of a linear map: $f(\boldsymbol{\beta}_1+\boldsymbol{\beta}_2)=f(\boldsymbol{\beta}_1)+f(\boldsymbol{\beta}_2)$ and for some scalar constant $\alpha$, that $f(\alpha\boldsymbol{\beta})=\alpha f(\boldsymbol{\beta})$.

If it is not immediately clear (or if you're unused to working with vectors and matrices), you can check those conditions for each of your example models.

For example your first model has $E(Y|x) = \beta_0\cdot 1+\beta_1 \cdot x = f(\beta_0,\beta_1)$. Now consider

\begin{eqnarray}
f((\beta_0+\gamma_0),(\beta_1+\gamma_1))&=& (\beta_0+\gamma_0)\cdot 1+(\beta_1+\gamma_1) \cdot x \\ &=& \beta_0\cdot 1+\beta_1 \cdot x + \gamma_0\cdot 1+\gamma_1 \cdot x\\ &=&f(\beta_0,\beta_1)+f(\gamma_0,\gamma_1)
\end{eqnarray}

That's the first condition; you can check the second condition in a similar way.

No doubt that seems trivial to the point of banality - but once you have linearity, a lot follows from that. Linear algebra underlies a large number of widely used statistical models and it's worth learning some of the basics before trying to understand a theorem like Gauss-Markov.