# Too good results with linear regression on a non-linear dataset due to training on seen data?

Tags: regression, linear-model, supervised-learning

I plotted some time series data that looks non-linear as can be seen below.
![Text] [[image: Open stock prices over time period]Looks pretty non-linear, but I decided to implement a linear regression model for learnings sake.

```
train_data = df["High"].iloc[:math.ceil(10382*0.8)].to_numpy().reshape(8306, 1)

y_data = df["High"].iloc[1:math.ceil(10382*0.8)+1].to_numpy().reshape(8306, 1)
```

As you can see, I have actually decided to try using the exact same series data as the X and Y values. Just I have shifted the positions of data by 1.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model_lr = LinearRegression().fit(train_data, y_data)
```

When I scored the training results, `model_lr.score(train_data, y_data)`, the coefficient of determination is good (0.9996742517879881), nearly 1.

I thought it was just overfitting but when I predicted values,

```
pred = model_lr.predict(test_data)
model_lr.score(pred, y_test_data)
```

The coefficient is good as well (0.9992371497078137).  If the data I used was non-linear, is the problem here that I am using the same series data to model it? As I don't think a linear model should be performing well on non-linear data.

I thought it would be ok using the same series data to model if it mimicks actual inflow of stock price data.  So as data flows in, just plug that into the model.

Is the linear regression model simply taking the previous series data and adding a small bias only? Is that how it is getting so accurate?

I plotted the predictions to the test data, and it looks like this weird straight line. Note also that this is not multiple regression.
[image: The predictions plotted against actual test data]

Comment: Sort the predictions. Also if this is linear regression without any polynomial terms or such then a straight line is expected.

Comment: What does sorting the predictions mean in this case?

Answer (score 1):

> Looks pretty non-linear, but I decided to implement a linear regression model for learnings sake. [...]
> As you can see, I have actually decided to try using the exact same series data as the X and Y values. Just I have shifted the positions of data by 1.

Then your initial plot is quite useless. The function $E[y|x] = f(x)$ is supposed to be [linear in parameters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279424/gauss-markov-theorem-what-do-you-mean-by-linearity-in-parameters). It's irrelevant that $E[y|t] = g(t)$, where $t$ is time, is non-linear. So the plot you should look at is $y$ against $x$, so in this case against lagged $y$.

> When I scored the training results, `model_lr.score(train_data, y_data)`, the coefficient of determination is good (0.9996742517879881), nearly 1.

Now try calculating $R^2$ where `y_pred = train_data`, without any model. Likely the result would be equally good. In time-series like this $y_t$ and $y_{t-1}$ are highly correlated, so you can easily get a "highly performing" model that didn't learn anything useful. Also, keep in mind that taking the last value as your prediction is a valid way of forecasting, it's called the [naïve forecasting method](https://otexts.com/fpp3/simple-methods.html#na%C3%AFve-method), the only problem with it is that if you try to predict more than one step ahead, you would be predicting a constant.

> Is the linear regression model simply taking the previous series data and adding a small bias only? Is that how it is getting so accurate?

Adding small bias, or not adding anything at all, as discussed above.

> I plotted the predictions to the test data, and it looks like this weird straight line. Note also that this is not multiple regression.

Because you used the wrong plot. Use a scatter plot instead. There is no need whatsoever to "connect the dots". From the plot, we already can see that the points need to lie in a straight line.

Comment: Consider that using today's temperature to predict tomorrow's is a better idea than using the annual mean, but it's not a contribution to meteorology or any kind of achievement.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding what is actually going on, would you happen to have recommendations for statistics resources for probability? As I have some trouble following concepts such as E[y|x] = f(x) and linear in parameters.

Comment: @Urxtixt have you checked the linked thread? You can also search the site for „linear in parameters”. The topics should be covered by any introductory statistics handbook.

Comment: I can vaguely guess what the idea is from the linked thread.

Comment: @Urxtixt TL;DR it means that linear regression is a (noisy) [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) (see also [Khan's Accademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-home/alg-linear-eq-func)). It does not need to look like a line on the plot. In your case, you plotted $y$ as a function of time, while linear regression does not make any assumption that there is any relation between time and $y$, but between $x$ and $y$ (unless $x$ is time).